# MIPS program for calculating n choose k using recursion

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I started a course of assembly and I am using MIPS as the programming language. I try to solve the problem of n choose k. Here is the code that I got so far but it always shows 1 as the result.

```
# Calculate n choose k
#
# n: integer value for n
# k: integer value for k
#
# Return: integer value for n choose k

.text
.globl nChooseK

nChooseK:
    # Check if k is equal to 0 or k is equal to n
    beq $a1, $zero, return_1
    beq $a1, $a0, return_1

    # Calculate n-1 choose k-1
    sub $t0, $a0, 1
    sub $t1, $a1, 1
    jal nChooseK
    move $t2, $v0

    # Calculate n-1 choose k
    move $a0, $a0
    move $a1, $t1
    jal nChooseK
    move $t3, $v0

    # Return the sum of the two calculations
    add $v0, $t2, $t3
    jr $ra

return_1:
    # Return 1 if k is equal to 0 or k is equal to n
    li $v0, 1

# Print the result of n choose k
.globl main

main:
    li $a0, 5     # Load the value of n into $a0
    li $a1, 3      # Load the value of k into $a1
    #jal nChooseK   # Call the nChooseK function
    move $a0, $v0  # Load the result into $a0
    li $v0, 1      # Set $v0 to 1 to print an integer
    syscall        # Print the result
    
    li $v0, 10     # Set $v0 to 10 to exit the program
    syscall        # Exit the program
```

Comment: Take a look at [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Debugging assembly language is very similar to any other language.  Single step each line and verify that the program state is correct between each line.  If you find something unexpected, that's were to take a closer look.  Sometimes we miss something that is wrong and the real error happened earlier.  That's ok, just back up a bit in the program flow and find who made the bad data or decision.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping?  If so, what is the first instruction to run?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
return_1:
    # Return 1 if k is equal to 0 or k is equal to n
    li $v0, 1
    # fallthrough into main (comment added by me). Put jr $ra here
# Print the result of n choose k
.globl main
```

Regardless of your input, eventually one of your recursions will have to return 1 as a base case. So, what's happening is, you're setting `$v0` to 1 and going back into main. Now, that being said, I'm not sure why this doesn't result in an infinite loop, since you'd end up calling `nChooseK` over and over again and overflow the stack. Could be that you've commented out the `jal nChooseK` down at the bottom.

Comment: Indeed if I would've not have commented out the line `jal nChooseK` It would've entered an infinite loop. 
I have added the `jr $ra` line and now it throws an error which says 
`Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000` .

Comment: I have tried stepping into the code one line at the time with values for `n=1` and `k=1`. It first goes into the `nChooseK` function and because `n == k` it goes straight into the `return_1` function and there is the place where it throws the error above.

Comment: An invalid program counter value suggests to me that the function is trying to return more often than it was called.